# delete a former label tk python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label, tk-toolkit

im developing an application with Tkinter module using python, but i have an issue i cant solve.

the application takes info from the user and then place this informtion and place it on the screen (for example name,age,department)

```
*****
Name     Age     Department
joni      21     system
Noam      37     electronics

*****
```

if the user inseted a few raws, i want him to be able to delete every row he wants, and to oder the lines under the deleted line to go up one line (so i wouldnt have a "hole" from the deleted line)

the thing is, after you create a few Labes in tk, you dont know what Label the user deleted.
is there a way to get info from the label that destroyed?like number?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "you don't know what Label the user deleted"? You are writing the code that lets them delete it, why don't you know?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is by storing the information in a class for example :

```
class foo: 
    def __init__(self, name, age, department):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age
       self.department = department
```

Then in your main program you could make a list of instances of this class for instance

```
import foo
refFoo = []

#get user input and store in variables name, age, dept

refFoo.append(foo.foo(name, age, dept))
```

Then copy this into your working list

```
Foo = list(refFoo)
```

then you can delete items from Foo keeping all the items in refFoo intact.

To display call something like

```
def displayItems(Foo):
    numOfItems = len(Foo)

    print("Name\tAge\tDepartment")

    for i in numOfItems:
        print(Foo[i].name, '\t',  Foo[i].age, '\t', Foo[i].department)

    after(1000, displayItems(Foo) #displays up to date list
```

the after() will re-call the function every second (1000ms) so you dont need to worry about the gaps.

I have not tested this code but it should work.

That is the way I would do it